# Unit Tests never execute

Tags: c++, unit-testing, uwp, mstest

I've been having some issues just getting the basic c++ unit test project to run a simple unit test.

So far I have:

1. Created a blank Visual C++ Unit Test App (Universal Windows)
2. Added a very simple test to the default Test_Method provided in the default UnitTest.cpp class.
3. Built and run the test app against the Local Machine. The default unit test UI appears when the app launches.

But my test does not run. the default UI appears and just sits there with the message "Tests Running". Even opening the Test Explorer and explicitly running all tests results in a similar situation, although running the tests this way causes the test to spin forever.

I hope I'm just doing something simple wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any ideas why my tests never fire?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Image of Default App UI]

[image: Image of Basic Test]

Comment: Update : I've tested a brand new c++ project, c# project, I've tested from the command line with vstest.console.exe and also created an xUnit project. So far the xUnit project is the only one that does not encounter this problem. I'm not particularly happy about this as all my code is in c++, not c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested everything trying to find what was wrong. I ran VS as an admin, I turned off the Firewall, I ran VS in safemode from the dev-console (this causes the Test Explorer to throw an exception funny enough), and I created about 30 different new projects trying to see if it was just a problem with my first project. In every case, it was the same : the app would open, close, and the unit tests would never resolve.

At the end of the day, the only solution I found was to swap out to a new computer. This is a really crappy solution, but the problem seemed completely isolated to my laptop.